# Return string from Web Api 2 using HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

Having web api 2 controller that reads from a file and returns a string:

```
public string Get()
{
    return service.Read();
}
```

I'm calling this get method using HttpClient like so:

```
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient()) {
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(_url);
        var response = httpClient.GetStringAsync("api/Values/").Result;

        Console.WriteLine(response);
    }
```

however it returns extra "\r\n" characters. Is this the proper way to return a string? I don't want "\r\n" - how would I do it? Doing string replace? is that correct approach?

Comment: `GetStringAsync` returns what you send. If there are newlines, that means they already existed in the response body. Use Fiddler to check what the actual response body is

Comment: BTW, how did you check that there *are* extra newlines? What does `service.Read()` do? Have you tried returning a dummy string like `ABCD`? What does the response string contain in this case?

Comment: in the file i have a single line "hello"

Comment: If you view the text file in Visual Studio and turn on the display of whitespace, can you see any new line characters?

Comment: that worked. thanks

Comment: How can I get rid of ""?

Comment: @BobSwanson the same way you got rid of `\n`. Either remove it from the file or check if there *really* is such a character in there and you don't confuse the values in the Watch window for something else. In any case, you *still* haven't posted code or data that reproduces your problem, so one can only guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file already contains that new line.

Put a debug breakpoint in the controller to verify the output of `service.Read()`.

`GetStringAsync` returns exactly what's received from server, without adding new lines etc.